# Best way to capture a certain substring?

Tags: regex, vb.net, text

*I have a file with content like:*

```
garbage
garbage
printfile ps = "Elopak Zufriedenheit After Sales.ps";
garbage
garbage
```

I want to capture the part between `""`  (double quotes) - but the value of that part changes constantly. I have written a  **regex** to find the `printfile ps` - but what is the best way to proceed from there?

The new code:

```
Dim PFileRegex As New Regex("printfile ps *\t*= *\t*""[\w\s]*.ps\s*""") 
Dim PFilematch As Match = PFileRegex.Match(parttext)

                    If PFilematch.Success = True Then
                        Dim Quote As Char = """"c
                        Dim FirstQuote = PFilematch.Value.IndexOf(Quote)
                        Dim LastQuote = PFilematch.Value.LastIndexOf(Quote)

                        Dim PSFile = PFilematch.Value.Substring(FirstQuote + 1, (LastQuote - FirstQuote) - 1)
                        Debug.Print(PSFile)
                    Else
                        'error handlung
                    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using the `Regex` class:

```
Dim PFileRegex As New Regex("^printfile ps\s*=\s*""(?<data>.*\.ps\s*)"";.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim PFilematch As Match = PFileRegex.Match(parttext)
If PFilematch.Success Then
    Debug.Print(PFilematch.Result("${data}"))
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a regex for this? `String.Substring` is more efficient.

```
Dim quote As Char = """"c
Dim first = printfilePs.IndexOf(quote)
Dim last = printfilePs.LastIndexOf(quote)
Dim partBetweenQuotes = ""
If first <> -1 AndAlso last > first Then
     Dim start = first + 1
     Dim length = printfilePs.Length - start - (printfilePs.Length - last)
     partBetweenQuotes = printfilePs.Substring(start, length)
End If
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/fbSfC2)

Comment: There is a lot of text around this piece - especially there are a lot of Quotes ("). The first and the last quote may not at the expected places.
Also, there are other key- value pairs I have to parse - so I thaught a regex would be the most versatile approach.
I am basically parsing hand written syntax files - and the order of the syntax file might be different eacht time

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the value after "prinfile ps = ":

```
printfile ps *= *"([^"]+)";
```

If you want to get all key-value couples:

```
^([^= ]+) *= *"([^"]+)";$
```

Comment: That does not work for me - i have used the following code:
 Dim PFileRegex As New Regex("printfile ps *= *""([^""]+)"";")